# Send local notification at a certain time of the day

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to get a random string from an array and then display this everyday at 7am.

Here is the code in my AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{ 

    QuoteTableViewController *quoteVC;
        int randomlyGeneratedNumber;
        randomlyGeneratedNumber =arc4random()%[quoteVC.arrayOfOurQuotes count];
        NSString *stringOfTheDay = [[NSString alloc] init];
        stringOfTheDay = [quoteVC.arrayOfOurQuotes objectAtIndex:randomlyGeneratedNumber];
        NSLog(@"%@",stringOfTheDay);

        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

        [componentsForReferenceDate setDay:9];
        [componentsForReferenceDate setMonth:11];
        [componentsForReferenceDate setYear:2012];

        NSDate *referenceDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForReferenceDate];
        NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond ) fromDate: referenceDate];

        [componentsForFireDate setHour:7];
        [componentsForFireDate setMinute:0];
        [componentsForFireDate setSecond:0];

        NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate];

        // Create the notification

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (notification) {
            notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification;
            notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
            notification.repeatInterval = 0;
            notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:stringOfTheDay];
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        }
}
```

There is a error at this line when i run the code

```
randomlyGeneratedNumber =arc4random()%[quoteVC.arrayOfOurQuotes count];
```

There is an array in my other View Controller. I did import the view controller.

EDIT :
Array has strings inside but when imported into app delegate it becomes 0. How to fix this?

Comment: Neither QuoteTableViewController or arrayOfOurQuotes seems to be initialized

Comment: What kind of error? If [quoteVC.arrayOfOurQuotes count] is zero, you will get a divide by zero exception in the % operation. Is that the problem?

Comment: arrayOfOurQuotes us initialised in the other view controller

Comment: the error says `Thread 1: EXC_ARTHIMETIC(code=EXC_l386_DIV,subdued=0x0)`

Comment: Just a side note, it is better to use `arc4random_uniform` to generate random number. In your example: `randomlyGeneratedNumber = arc4random_uniform([quoteVC.arrayOfOurQuotes count]);`

Comment: The error means that you dividing by zero which means that [quoteVC.arrayOfOurQuotes count] returns zero. Either quoteVC.arrayOfOurQuotes is nil or has zero elements.

Comment: but i do have strings inside the array

Comment: When i log the number of strings in my view controller `viewDidLoad` it says 3 but then when i log it in the app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it says 0

Comment: then how would i fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement 'arrayOfOurQuotes' as a property of your App delegate instead of the view controller. The view controller and therefore your array will not be around anymore when the view is gone - which is obviously the case if you have already entered the background.

Comment: but if that is the case won't i have to create another array and add all the strings into it?

Comment: No. You can access it from your View Controller like this: ((YourAppDelegateType *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate). arrayOfOurQuotes;

Comment: I usually use a macro to make this easier, like this: `#define MYAPP ((YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)` in my AppDelegate.h file. This reduces the access to MYAPP.arrayOfOurQuotes.

Comment: then how would i do it in the app delegate?

Comment: what is a macro?? sorry i am just a beginner

Comment: If you don't want to use "fancy macros" just add a property of type YourAppDelegateType to your ViewController (call it app or so), set it to `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` at init or load time and use `app.arrayOfOurQuotes` to access your array inside your ViewController.